# LAN (Wi-Fi): Cannot ping android to pc and vice-versa, but pc to pc works

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, android

I have 2 independent routers(each with its own WAN). All my devices have the same static IPs with these routers.
Router 1 gateway 192.168.1.1, Router 2 gateway 192.168.1.100

I connected these 2 routers with an ethernet cable by their LAN ports. I have 2 win 10 pcs, chromecast v1, and an android 11 device. Each pc is connected to one router, chromecast to one router and the phone can connect to any router.

The pc connected to router 2 can ping the other pc and chromecast connected to router 1 and vice versa. But it can only ping the mobile if its connected to router 2.
If a pc and mobile are under different routers, they can't ping eachother. But all other devices can communicate irrespective of router.

Why aren't android device and pc on different routers not accessible to the other whereas pc-pc and pc-chromecast can discover eachother?

Is this an android issue, what can I do to fix it?

After further testing, I found that if I connect the pc to router through ethernet, the problem does not arise and all devices are discoverable.

Comment: Do all the involved devices have the 'subnet mask' configured correctly?

Comment: Yes, 255.255.255.0 is what the routers are configured with. All devices show the same.